# Lua search through table

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I am working on a game project using Corona SDK and I am running into an issue. I am trying to use string.find() in a for loop to test to determine if a value is in a certain table and if so, add that value to another table. My problem is that since string.find()/string.match does not read duplicates in this case (assuming that the for loop is the reason why). I am essentially only having "1102", "1103" instead of "1102", "1102", "1103", "1102", in the "copy" table which is how I am trying to get this to do. Any suggestions?

```
database = 
{
 {name="test", serial="1102", img="src/1.png"},
 {name="test2", serial="1103", img="src/2.png"},
 {name="test3", serial="1104", img="src/3.png"}
}

list = 
{
 "1102",
 "1102",
 "1103",
 "1102"
}

copy = {}
n=1

for i=1, #database do
 if string.find(database[i].serial, tostring(list[n])) then 
   table.insert(copy, database[i].img)
   n=n+1
 end
end    
for i=1, #copy do 
    print(copy[i])
end
```

Comment: What is `n` in `tostring(list[n])`?  You want to match a value in `database` if its `serial` matches **any** of `list` or a specific one? What do the duplicate elements in `list` mean?

Comment: Meant to add n=1 so each find is n=n+1 to go to the next index. Basically what I am trying to do is match the serial in 'list' with 'database'  and each time it does, add the img value to the 'copy'  table. The biggest thing is that I need it do this even for duplicates like the 3 "1102" serials, in the order appearing in 'list'. The copy table is then used to draw the images, even duplicates. I cannot figure this out. I am thinking a for loop but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: With your example input, you expect `copy` to have one `"src/1.png"` and one `"src/2.png"`, is this correct?

Comment: The code has it reading as: src/1.png, src/2.png however, it needs to be reading as `src/1.png`, `src/1.png`, `src/3.png`, `src/1.png` which follows how 'list' is setup.

Comment: I am stuck on how to traverse through the table this way until `list` has all of its `img` put into `copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a nested loop works.

```
for lk, lv in ipairs(list) do
  for dk, dv in ipairs(database) do
    if string.find(dv.serial, tostring(lv)) then 
      table.insert(copy, dv.img)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using `ipairs`, which is similar to `for i=1, #list do`.

Answer (score 0):

Are the serials in the database table unique? If so, From the code, I think you can make your database table to be more efficient.

```
local database = 
{
 [1102] = {name="test", img="src/1.png"},
 [1103] = {name="test2", img="src/2.png"},
 [1104] = {name="test3", img="src/3.png"}
}
```

Note that, with this change, you cannot use iterative for loops to navigate in the database table. However, the part where you do the check becomes this:

```
local list = {1102,1102,1103,1102,}
local copy = {};
for index, serial in next, list do 
    if database[serial] then copy[#copy+1] = database[serial].img end
end
```

For the last part, you can use `table.concat()` to print values of a table as a string, instead of iterating over it one by one:

```
table.concat(copy, "\n")
```

And lastly, I know the code you've written up there is an example, but be careful about global variables; I hope they (database, list, copy) are not global in your code. Anyway,

With Regards, lyr

Comment: Then you can use those serials as the keys in the database table; like shown above.